# elasticsearch multi statement in match section

Tags: elasticsearch

I newly become familiar with elasticsearch and I have two question. firstly I want to create an index to show any "exception" or "error" or "fatal" in kibana.something like that

```
    "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "template1": {
        "mapping": {
          "doc_values": true,
          "ignore_above": 50000,
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "{dynamic_type}"
        },
        "match": " error exception fatal ..."
      }
    }
  ],
```

how should I handle multi statment in match section?

My second question is about finding any word that has exactly 24 characters and start with 4 letters then 8 digits and finally the combination of digit and latter. How can I write match section in my index pattern
thank you

Comment: There is no resposnse.???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@timestamp:[now-1d TO now] AND host:db2-rhe73.siam AND message:(erro* OR exception OR fatal)